# Put text under image

Tags: css, html, image

[image: current state]

[image: what I need]

How to put the text right under icons ? I need the hyperlink to be the same like for the icon. When I enter text it's always shown on the right of the icon. When I put 
 or

it's also affecting other icons.

The HTML code:

```
  <div style="margin-top:-35px">

<a href="panel.php?module=ustawienia"><img alt="" src="gfx/ustawienia.png" class="noborder"/></a><span class="imgmove"></span>

<a href="panel.php?module=zablokowane"><img alt="" src="gfx/zablokowane_strony.png" class="noborder"/></a><span class="imgmove"></span>

<a href="panel.php?module=tagi"><img alt="" src="gfx/tagi.png" class="noborder"/></a><span class="imgmove"></span>

<a href="panel.php?module=users"><img alt="" src="gfx/uzytkownicy.png" class="noborder"/></a><span class="imgmove"></span>

<a href="panel.php?module=RSSadmin"><img alt="" src="gfx/zarzadzanie_newsami.png" class="noborder"/></a><span class="imgmove"></span>

<a href="panel.php?module=narzedzia"><img alt="" src="gfx/narzedzia_wyszukiwarek.png" class="noborder"/></a><span class="imgmove"></span><p>

<a href="panel.php?module=swl"><img alt="" src="gfx/swl.png" class="noborder"/></a>

</div>

CSS code:

    .noborder{
    border:0;
    display: inline;
    text-align:center; 
}

.imgmove
{
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

Comment: Display:block will show everything in one column :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you put the image text (the `<span>`) *inside* the link element (the `<a>`). This way, whenever the link is moved around, the text will follow the image. Which would give you this:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">
        <img alt="" src="..." />
        <span>Text here</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img alt="" src="..." />
        <span>Text here</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

If you then set `display:block` to both the image and the text, the text will be put under the image. Like this:

```
.container a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* Adjust if multi-line text */
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 120px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container a img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 0;
}
.container a span {
    display: block;
}
```

**Here's a [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2W3Ne/).**

Answer (score 0):

I found great example here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_gallery.asp

Works fine !

Answer (score -2):

Wrap each image in a table with 2 rows.  Then center the text in the bottom row.
See it in action HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5X9G/

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="panel.php?module=ustawienia">
                <img alt="" src="gfx/ustawienia.png" class="noborder" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align: center'>TEXT HERE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or perhaps you prefer using a div tag instead

```
<div style='text-align: center;>
    <a href="panel.php?module=ustawienia"><img alt="" src="gfx/ustawienia.png" class="noborder" /></a><br />
    TEXT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: So what do you recommend ?

Comment: Anything but tables for layout

Comment: Firstly, I gave two examples... Secondly, if you have any better recommendations, I would be very interested in seeing them.  Also, what you posted is exactly what I had.